# Visual Studio 2019: could not rename a file in the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a solution containing several projects. I can rename files in some projects but I could not do so in some other projects. The message is "The file ... could not be renamed. The most likely reason is that the file is under source control ...". Note that all projects in the solution are under git control.
So what is the cause and how to walk around the issue?

Comment: Did you carefully read the [documentation of Visual Studio and of WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) ? Consider using [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [git](http://git-scm.com/) on the command line and **read documentation**. Provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: @Basile I think you did not read my description. The issue has nothing to do with WinAPI or MingGW. It is just about VS IDE.

Comment: Then you need to take hours to **read the documentation** of VS IDE and if it still does not work like you want switch to other tools (and perhaps consider using some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer)